# sending message on youtube live chat with selenium using python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I was trying to make a script using python and selenium, to spam a massage on youtube live stream for a giveaway, i was able to do most of the task successfully until on line (33), where i was trying to locate the youtube live chat box by(**.find_element_by_...**?) it was showing all kind of error like,**AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute**  or **failed to locate element_by_...?** 'find_element_by_text,xpath,id.class, etc

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

email = ''
password = ''
gmail_link = 'http:\\www.gmail.com'

driver = webdriver.Firefox('D:\Projects\python projects')
driver.get(gmail_link)
time.sleep(4)

#email send_keys
driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)

#Email_next button xpath.click
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]   /div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/content/span').click()
time.sleep(4)

#password xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/content/section/div/content/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
#password button xpath.click
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2] /div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/content/span').click()

time.sleep(5)


#A random youtube live link
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTqTnbe6b1g')
time.sleep(5)
# youtube live chat box
driver.find_element_by_text('Say somthing...').send_keys('#PUBGMOBILE')
time.sleep(3)
# youtube live chat box button
driver.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="button"]').click()
```

Comment: Hacking is a fine and noble way to learn coding, but hacking requires _research_. Dumping a blob of untestable code into a question and talking vaguely about the errors it produces is not going to get much traction here. Stick to a specific problem and work from the known to the unknown. Show the _exact_ error message you get, along with any details we would need to understand what it is you are attempting. Also remember that every browser has a developer mode. You should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically that div is associated with 'input' event so you have to dispatch the 'input' event once you enter the value in the div.
Here is the code which I was able to execute successfully form console (FYI this is JS you can use the same logic in your test and language).

```
ele = document.querySelector('div#input')
ele.textContent = 'test this sample data'
ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('input',{'bubles':true, 'cancelable':true}))
```

Line 1 is equals findelemnt by css

Line 2 enter the input

Line 3 fireevent 'input' on the element

```
WebElement chatEle = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR('div#input')
chatEle.sendKeys "sample data"
driver.fireEvent(chatEle,"input")
```

should do the magic, couldn't test the code above as I don't have eclipse java environment on my machine. Test it and let us know.

Refer to [Selenium FireEvent](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/FireEvent.html) document for more information on the fireevent implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the element by its text you could use its xpath like you did before. I just looked at the chatbox for a YT livestream and the xpath seems to be called `//*[@id="input"]`

Edit:
Also, there could be something tricky where you need to click the element first before you can enter text.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did try the #xpath ('//*[@id="input"]') it did not worked its showing me (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="input"]) this error and i have no idea  how click the element first :(

Answer (score 0):

don't use the [@id="input"] it was also given for another element too. You will not get the element. Use class name {yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer style-scope} this is unique you will get the element by this class name.
Your sending text to a wrong element
     driver.find_element_by_text('Say somthing...').send_keys('#PUBGMOBILE')
This is lable not a textbox.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried class_name('yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer style-scope')
class_name('style-scope yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer style-scope yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer')

did not worked :(

Comment: i reply, i did not

Comment: what error you're getting now? if it's like not getting element then increase the time of sleep or use  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
            wait.until(expectation);

Comment: same selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .style-scope yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer style-scope yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer

Comment: You are using so many classes at one time, use only one unique class or any other selector which will just point to that element.